# for loop error, javascript closure

Tags: javascript, function

Why my for loop doesn't log different values of i on different line instead of it log 5 times 6.

**Here is the code snippet.**

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () { console.log(i); }, 1000);
}
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this it will work

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        (function(ind) {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(ind);}, 1000 + (1000 * ind));
        })(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks jignesh patel. But can u explain me why  my code is printing 5 times   6?

Comment: just setting a timeout for loop execution not stops. and when time out completed value of i is 6 as loop execution completed.

Comment: well, First of all i m beginner. U mean if i lowerthe timeout seconds then i will get different value? But i tried, the output is still same.

Comment: Is the loop firsth executed whole and i gets incremented to the 6, then afterwards timeout method start to executed?